# Troubleshooting a Chevrolet El Camino SS in 3D Modelling

Tags: modeling, topology

I have an issue about modelling a car which is a Chevrolet El Camino SS. I kept on deleting the object every time I am not satisfied with the topology of the car. It is a low poly model and it is not yet complete. I tried modelling the car in different positions but it did not work out.

I searched one car modelling tutorial but it is specific to one car - a BMW M3 E36. The tutorial was meant to be made for Roblox and I am trying to model my car for Roblox too. The link for the tutorial is here: https://youtu.be/AbfO0ryZ74k.

Also, I tried looking for a modelling tutorial for the El Camino SS but to no avail. I got the blueprints from the Internet and I looked for good reference photos about the car. I am still an amateur in modelling and modelling this one type of car is difficult. Will somebody give me help so that I could get a clue of where to start? I will provide the following photos and the .blend file to prove that I am not lying.

Incomplete Actual Model:
[image: Incomplete model of El Camino SS]

Blueprints:
[image: Front Blueprint]
[image: Rear Blueprint]
[image: Side Blueprint]
[image: Top Blueprint]

.blend File:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, import your images as *Images > References* or *Backgrounds*, rotate them so you have an image for all the orthographic views: Top, side, front... Then the best is probably to begin with the side view. Create an edge and extrude it along the shape:

[image]

Once done, switch to front view, extrude, mirror with the *Mirror* modifier, modify the shape according to the picture:

[image]

As you can see I already have the basic shape. Then continue with top view and so on...

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir or ma'am, this can help